# upgrade from hive0.10 to hive 0.12

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hbase

I have upgraded my hive from hive 0.10 to hive 0.12, hive 0.10 worked fine before, but now with hive 0.12 I've run into an exception when i executed a query like 
select count(*) from table1, any help will be really appreciated, thanks !!!

I have hadoop 1.0.3, hbase 0.92.1, hive 0.12

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.readByteArray(Bytes.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableSplit.readFields(TableSplit.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSplit.readFields(HBaseSplit.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat$HiveInputSplit.readFields(HiveInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

hive> describe tct;
OK
deviceid                string                  from deserializer   
level                   int                     from deserializer   
stage                   int                     from deserializer   
ispayer                 string                  from deserializer
```

Comment: Can you update with your `DESCRIBE table1;` command results?

Comment: @eliasah,i've updated my question, thanks. This is a good move i think

Comment: did you install hive from the CDH 4.3 repo?

Comment: @eliasah,No, i didn't use CDH distribution, i downloaded hive0.12.jar from apache directly

Comment: hive0.12.jar? and how are you running it?

Comment: @eliasah, i have all the needed components installed(hbase, hadoop etc),actually i thought maybe this related either to version of hadoop (hadoop1.0.3)or version of hbase(hbase0.92.1) that i have now